# list of commands in cron

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to wrap my head around this but I can't. I wanted to make a cron that checks a process is up. If so, write to a file that it is up. Else, use this script to start it again, and log the fact that it was dead.

Here's what I came up with:

```
pgrep -f app -u silv && echo "$(date) app is online" >> /home/silv/app_status || echo "$(date) app is dead" >> /home/silv/app_status && /home/silv/apps/app/bin/start-app.sh
```

If the app is up, it writes correctly in the log file, that it's online.
If the app is not up, it still writes that it is online BUT also start's the app.

What am I missing?

Comment: Properly double quote your process, `pgrep -f "app -u silv"`

Comment: no, actually that was just ugly formatting on my part. should be pgrep -f -u silv app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't understand how '&&' and '||' actually work in Bash.
This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88851) explains it, the gist being that both AND and OR operators have the same precedence in BASH